# Javascript regex capturing group

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following https://regex101.com/r/nqx8RE/1 regex and want to access the capturing groups only. I don't care about the whole matches. That is, I want ONLY the labels (16 in the example) without the label tags.

My code is very simple, and it's the following, but in the console.log I get an array with the whole `<label for="blah blah">label</label>` records.

```
var exp_code = $('#exp_iframe').contents().find('body').html();
exp_matches = exp_code.match(/<label for=".*">(.*)<\/label>/g);
console.log(exp_matches);
```

What am I doing wrong?

TIA.

Comment: Indeed it works! It isn't elegant at all, as you have to repeat the regex in the loop (strange JS), but it works! I wonder if there is any other way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
let m=[], s = document.body.innerHTML;

s.replace(/<label for=".*?">(.*?)<\/label>/g, (x,y)=> m.push(y));

console.log(m);
```

```js
let m=[], s = document.body.innerHTML;

s.replace(/<label for=".*?">(.*?)<\/label>/g, (x,y)=> m.push(y));

console.log(m);
```

```html
<body>
<form name="catalogue" action="test.php" method="GET">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group m-1">
          <label for="product">product</label>
          <select id="product" name="product" onChange="submitForm(this);">
            <option value="compliment_slips"  >Μηνύματα  αλληλογραφίας</option>
            <option value="stickers" selected >Aυτοκόλλητα</option>
          
            <option value="waiter_pads"  >μπλοκ σερβιτόρου</option>
            <option value="brochure wireO"  >σπιράλ βιβλιο</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group m-1">
          <label for="c_format">c_format</label>
          <select id="c_format" name="c_format" onChange="submitForm(this);">
            <option value="C_37_x_52_mm_DIN-A-9"  >37 x 52 mm DIN A9</option>
            <option value="C_50_x_20_mm_(abgerundete_Ecken)"  >50 x 20 mm (στρογγυλεμένες γωνίες)</option>
            <option value="C_52_x_74_mm_DIN-A-8"  >52 x 74 mm DIN A8</option>
            <option value="C_70_x_25_mm_(abgerundete_Ecken)"  >70 x 25 mm (στρογγυλεμένες γωνίες)</option>
            <option value="C_74_x_105_mm_DIN-A-7" selected >74 x 105 mm DIN A7</option>
            <option value="C_85_x_55_mm"  >85 x 55 mm</option>
            <option value="C_85_x_55_mm_(abgerundete_Ecken)"  >85 x 55 mm (στρογγυλεμένες γωνίες)</option>
            <option value="C_98_x_210_mm_DIN_Lang"  >98 x 210 mm DIΝ φαρδύ</option>
            <option value="C_105_x_148_mm_DIN-A-6"  >105 x 148 mm A6</option>
            <option value="C_105_x_297_mm_Long-Size"  >105 x 297 mm</option>
            <option value="C_148_x_210_mm_DIN-A-5"  >148 x 210 mm DIN A5</option>
            <option value="C_210_x_297_mm_DIN-A-4"  >210 x 297 mm DIN A4</option>
            <option value="C_297_x_420_mm_DIN-A-3"  >297 x 420 mm DIN A3</option>
            <option value="C_40_mm_Rund"  >40 mm Στρογγυλό</option>
            <option value="C_80_mm_Rund"  >80 mm Στρογγυλό</option>
            <option value="C_145_x_95_mm_Oval"  >145 x 95 mm Οβάλ</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group m-1">
          <label for="c_format_dir">c_format_dir</label>
          <select id="c_format_dir" name="c_format_dir" onChange="submitForm(this);">
            <option value="C_panel_format" selected >Κάθετο</option>
            <option value="C_landscape_format"  >Οριζόντιο</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group m-1">
          <label for="c_paper">c_paper</label>
          <select id="c_paper" name="c_paper" onChange="submitForm(this);">
            <option value="C_Haft_gloss_permanent_klebend" selected >Αυτοκόλλητο λευκό χαρτί (κατάλληλο για εσωτερική χρήση)</option>
            <option value="C_PP-Folie"  >Aυτοκόλλητη μεμβράνη λευκή (κατάλληλη για εξωτερική χρήση)</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group m-1">
          <label for="c_color">c_color</label>
          <select id="c_color" name="c_color" onChange="submitForm(this);">
            <option value="C_1/0-farbig_Black"  >1/0-χρωμο Μαύρο</option>
            <option value="C_4/0-farbig_Euroskala" selected >4/0-χρωμο CMYK</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group m-1">
          <label for="c_processing">c_processing</label>
          <select id="c_processing" name="c_processing" onChange="submitForm(this);">
            <option value="C_Cutt" selected >Κοπή</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group m-1">
          <label for="c_finishing">c_finishing</label>
          <select id="c_finishing" name="c_finishing" onChange="submitForm(this);">
            <option value="C_Ohne_Finishing" selected >Χωρίς</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group m-1">
          <label for="c_finishing_desc">c_finishing_desc</label>
          <select id="c_finishing_desc" name="c_finishing_desc" onChange="submitForm(this);">
            <option value="C_Ohne_Veredelung" selected >Χωρίς</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group m-1">
          <label for="quantity">quantity</label>
          <select id="quantity" name="quantity" onChange="submitForm(this);">
            <option value="1_quantity" selected >1 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="5_quantity"  >5 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="10_quantity"  >10 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="15_quantity"  >15 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="20_quantity"  >20 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="25_quantity"  >25 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="50_quantity"  >50 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="100_quantity"  >100 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="250_quantity"  >250 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="500_quantity"  >500 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="750_quantity"  >750 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="1000_quantity"  >1000 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="1500_quantity"  >1500 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="2000_quantity"  >2000 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="2500_quantity"  >2500 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="5000_quantity"  >5000 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="7500_quantity"  >7500 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="10000_quantity"  >10000 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="15000_quantity"  >15000 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="20000_quantity"  >20000 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="25000_quantity"  >25000 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="30000_quantity"  >30000 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="35000_quantity"  >35000 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="40000_quantity"  >40000 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="45000_quantity"  >45000 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="50000_quantity"  >50000 Τεμάχια</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group m-1">
          <label for="packing">packing</label>
          <select id="packing" name="packing" onChange="submitForm(this);">
            <option value="without_packing" selected >Χωρίς</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group m-1">
          <label for="shipping">shipping</label>
          <select id="shipping" name="shipping" onChange="submitForm(this);">
            <option value="standard" selected >Παράδοση Κανονικό έως 30.08.</option>
            <option value="economy"  >Παράδοση Economy έως 03.09.</option>
            <option value="express"  >Παράδοση Εξπρές έως 29.08.</option>
            <option value="priority"  >Παράδοση Προτεραιότητα έως 22.08.</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

</body>
```

Or fresh [matchAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) (currently support by firefox and chrome, not by safari)

```
[...s.matchAll(/<label for=".*?">(.*?)<\/label>/g)].map(x=>x[1])
```

```js
let s = document.body.innerHTML;

let m=[...s.matchAll(/<label for=".*?">(.*?)<\/label>/g)].map(x=>x[1])

console.log(m);
```

```html
<body>
<form name="catalogue" action="test.php" method="GET">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group m-1">
          <label for="product">product</label>
          <select id="product" name="product" onChange="submitForm(this);">
            <option value="brochure wireO"  >σπιράλ βιβλιο</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group m-1">
          <label for="c_format">c_format</label>
          <select id="c_format" name="c_format" onChange="submitForm(this);">
            <option value="C_37_x_52_mm_DIN-A-9"  >37 x 52 mm DIN A9</option>
            <option value="C_50_x_20_mm_(abgerundete_Ecken)"  >50 x 20 mm (στρογγυλεμένες γωνίες)</option>
            <option value="C_52_x_74_mm_DIN-A-8"  >52 x 74 mm DIN A8</option>
            <option value="C_70_x_25_mm_(abgerundete_Ecken)"  >70 x 25 mm (στρογγυλεμένες γωνίες)</option>
            <option value="C_74_x_105_mm_DIN-A-7" selected >74 x 105 mm DIN A7</option>
            <option value="C_85_x_55_mm"  >85 x 55 mm</option>
            <option value="C_85_x_55_mm_(abgerundete_Ecken)"  >85 x 55 mm (στρογγυλεμένες γωνίες)</option>
            <option value="C_98_x_210_mm_DIN_Lang"  >98 x 210 mm DIΝ φαρδύ</option>
            <option value="C_105_x_148_mm_DIN-A-6"  >105 x 148 mm A6</option>
            <option value="C_105_x_297_mm_Long-Size"  >105 x 297 mm</option>
            <option value="C_148_x_210_mm_DIN-A-5"  >148 x 210 mm DIN A5</option>
            <option value="C_210_x_297_mm_DIN-A-4"  >210 x 297 mm DIN A4</option>
            <option value="C_297_x_420_mm_DIN-A-3"  >297 x 420 mm DIN A3</option>
            <option value="C_40_mm_Rund"  >40 mm Στρογγυλό</option>
            <option value="C_80_mm_Rund"  >80 mm Στρογγυλό</option>
            <option value="C_145_x_95_mm_Oval"  >145 x 95 mm Οβάλ</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group m-1">
          <label for="c_format_dir">c_format_dir</label>
          <select id="c_format_dir" name="c_format_dir" onChange="submitForm(this);">
            <option value="C_panel_format" selected >Κάθετο</option>
            <option value="C_landscape_format"  >Οριζόντιο</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group m-1">
          <label for="c_paper">c_paper</label>
          <select id="c_paper" name="c_paper" onChange="submitForm(this);">
            <option value="C_Haft_gloss_permanent_klebend" selected >Αυτοκόλλητο λευκό χαρτί (κατάλληλο για εσωτερική χρήση)</option>
            <option value="C_PP-Folie"  >Aυτοκόλλητη μεμβράνη λευκή (κατάλληλη για εξωτερική χρήση)</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group m-1">
          <label for="c_color">c_color</label>
          <select id="c_color" name="c_color" onChange="submitForm(this);">
            <option value="C_1/0-farbig_Black"  >1/0-χρωμο Μαύρο</option>
            <option value="C_4/0-farbig_Euroskala" selected >4/0-χρωμο CMYK</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group m-1">
          <label for="c_processing">c_processing</label>
          <select id="c_processing" name="c_processing" onChange="submitForm(this);">
            <option value="C_Cutt" selected >Κοπή</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group m-1">
          <label for="c_finishing">c_finishing</label>
          <select id="c_finishing" name="c_finishing" onChange="submitForm(this);">
            <option value="C_Ohne_Finishing" selected >Χωρίς</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group m-1">
          <label for="c_finishing_desc">c_finishing_desc</label>
          <select id="c_finishing_desc" name="c_finishing_desc" onChange="submitForm(this);">
            <option value="C_Ohne_Veredelung" selected >Χωρίς</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group m-1">
          <label for="quantity">quantity</label>
          <select id="quantity" name="quantity" onChange="submitForm(this);">
            <option value="1_quantity" selected >1 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="5_quantity"  >5 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="10_quantity"  >10 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="15_quantity"  >15 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="20_quantity"  >20 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="25_quantity"  >25 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="50_quantity"  >50 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="100_quantity"  >100 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="250_quantity"  >250 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="500_quantity"  >500 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="750_quantity"  >750 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="1000_quantity"  >1000 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="1500_quantity"  >1500 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="2000_quantity"  >2000 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="2500_quantity"  >2500 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="5000_quantity"  >5000 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="7500_quantity"  >7500 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="10000_quantity"  >10000 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="15000_quantity"  >15000 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="20000_quantity"  >20000 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="25000_quantity"  >25000 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="30000_quantity"  >30000 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="35000_quantity"  >35000 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="40000_quantity"  >40000 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="45000_quantity"  >45000 Τεμάχια</option>
            <option value="50000_quantity"  >50000 Τεμάχια</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group m-1">
          <label for="packing">packing</label>
          <select id="packing" name="packing" onChange="submitForm(this);">
            <option value="without_packing" selected >Χωρίς</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group m-1">
          <label for="shipping">shipping</label>
          <select id="shipping" name="shipping" onChange="submitForm(this);">
            <option value="standard" selected >Παράδοση Κανονικό έως 30.08.</option>
            <option value="economy"  >Παράδοση Economy έως 03.09.</option>
            <option value="express"  >Παράδοση Εξπρές έως 29.08.</option>
            <option value="priority"  >Παράδοση Προτεραιότητα έως 22.08.</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

</body>
```

Comment: WOW, what variation of JS is this? So compact and complex style! Is it prototype?

Comment: Thanks a Lot Kamil!